# if-codition of a loop into a pgfplotstable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, pgffor

I create a table with `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` and I test numbers whether they are even or odd. 
`\pgfmathsetmacro\eotest{mod(\n,2)==0 ? 1 : 0}` works correctly in the loop. 
For `\ifnum\eotest=1 \def\eoword{even} \else \def\eoword{odd} \fi`  
A `Direct writeout: \n,  \eotest,  \eoword \\` in the loop works too.

But if I put this all into a `\pgfplotstable`, that means 
`create on use/eoword/.style={create col/set={\eoword}}`, 
the 'eoword' is not shown correctly.
It only ever returns the last entry in the list. 
*What do I have to do differently?*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\section{Table Row by Row with a Loop}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \n in {0,...,8}{%%
% works: 
\pgfmathsetmacro\eotest{mod(\n,2)==0 ? 1 : 0}
%Problem here ========================  
\ifnum\eotest=1 \def\eoword{even} \else \def\eoword{odd} \fi% eoword 1/3
%Direct writeout: {\n,  \eotest,  \eoword} works well \\ 
% ================================
\pgfplotstablenew[
create on use/No/.style={create col/expr={\n}},
create on use/eotest/.style={create col/expr={\eotest}},
create on use/eoword/.style={create col/set={\eoword}},% eoword 2/3
columns={No, eotest, eoword}
]{1}\temptable
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\table}{\temptable}%
}%%

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns/eoword/.style={string type},% eoword 3/3
]{\table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `.estyle` so the value is expanded at the time the key is set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\section{Table Row by Row with a Loop}

\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \n in {0,...,8}{%%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\eotest{mod(\n,2)==0 ? 1 : 0}%
  \ifnum\eotest=1 \def\eoword{even} \else \def\eoword{odd} \fi% eoword 1/3
  \pgfplotstablenew[
    create on use/No/.style={create col/expr={\n}},
    create on use/eotest/.estyle={create col/expr={\eotest}},
    create on use/eoword/.estyle={create col/set={\eoword}},% eoword 2/3
    columns={No, eotest, eoword}
  ]{1}\temptable
  \pgfplotstablevertcat{\table}{\temptable}%
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/eoword/.style={string type},% eoword 3/3
]{\table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OMD :) It was worth to set the 'tikz-pgf'-task. Looking into pgfplotstable.pdf after `.estyle` - forget it. Thank you very much!